# Center align text to the bottom of a div

Tags: css, alignment

Basically I got the text on the bottom of the div where I like, but the problem is it's aligning left and I would like for it to be in the center of my div.

CSS3

```
#article-footer {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#article-footer {
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #354175;
}

#article-footer span{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: use text-align: center for that

Comment: do you have html code?

Comment: Yeah HTML5, but the CSS pretty much explains it, the text is just three words "BUY * SELL * TRADE"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#article-footer span{
position:absolute;
bottom: 0; 
left:50%;
margin-left:-50%;}
```

Comment: Then you should see what rule is overwriting it. Using `!important` is a bad idea

Comment: Got it centered using a version of this code edited a bit. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user3071842 If the span is single child of the footer, you don't need  to use `position:absolute`, just `display:block` on the span, and `text-align:center` on #article-footer

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
text-align: center !important ;
```

Comment: This works, I generally don't like using the !important rule if I can avoid it because it could make it more difficult for anyone wanting to alter my code in the future.